# Weird behaviour, why cannot use outermost variable in a function?

Tags: python, function, variables

I wrote a starter for a word guessing game. After a guess, the blanks is either updated, or not (either correct or incorrect guess). Here is the code:

```
blanks = "*********"
def check(word, guess):

    if guess == word:
        print("Correct guess: "+guess)
        blanks = word
        return blanks
    else:
        input("wrong guess (press any key)")
        return blanks

secretword = "Macedonia"
guess = input("type your guess: ")
result = check(secretword, guess)
```

When `check` is implemented and the `else` conditiin satisfied, the blanks cannot be used. But the blanks in the `if` condition can be used.

*When I comment the `blanks=word`, the code works fine.

Why is this? Thought global variables can be referenced anywhere. Thanks

**WHY DOWN VOTES? The question is clear and not a duplicate, and it is not provocative. And it is useful.**

Comment: inside your `else` block,  `blanks` is `undefined`.

Comment: To access a variable you need to define it first.

Comment: Edited the questiion @norrius

Comment: `blanks` should be defined inside the method

Comment: Globals strike again! Once you assign to a variable inside a scope, it is considered local. Use the `global` keyword.

Comment: @AriefAnbiya you may accept an answer to close this question, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global variables may indeed be referenced anywhere, but when you assign to a variable inside a function unless you tell Python otherwise that variable is a local variable throughout the function. So `blanks` inside the function has no relation to `blanks` outside the function.

When the code takes the `else` path it attempts to reference the local `blanks` but no value has yet been assigned so you will get an exception `UnboundLocalError`.

To fix this you must tell Python that the assignment inside the function is an assignment to the global `blanks`:

```
def check(word, guess):
    global blanks
    ... rest of code
```

The presence of an assignment anywhere inside a function will make that variable local everywhere in the function unless you use a `global` or `nonlocal` statement. It does not matter whether the assignment is executed or even whether it could be executed:

```
y = 0
def foo():
    return y # This is a local variable (but unbound so will error)
    y = 1    # this is unreachable but still makes `y` local.
```

Comment: I thought global var is referenced  by automatic?notice that when I comment the `blanks=word` the code works fine

Comment: Yes, if you only reference the variable it will use the global. If you attempt to assign to the variable then it will be an assignment to a local variable.

Comment: Even if the assignment is not actually impelemented after running the code?

Comment: Yes, the presence of an assignment anywhere in the function makes it a local variable everywhere in the function.

Answer (score -1):

The variable `blanks` should be defined inside the method `check` for it to be able to use it.

```
def check(word, guess):
    blanks = ""
    if guess == word:
        print("Correct guess: "+guess)
        blanks = word
        return blanks
    else:
        input("wrong guess (press any key)")
        return blanks
```

OR

if you want to use it `globally`:

```
blanks = "*********"

def check(word, guess):
    global blanks
    if guess == word:
        print("Correct guess: "+guess)
        blanks = word
        return blanks
    else:
        input("wrong guess (press any key)")
        return blanks

secretword = "Macedonia"
guess = input("type your guess: ")
result = check(secretword, guess)
```